# how to set position of icon in the alert dialog

Tags: android

How to set position of icon in the alert dialog? below is the code I am using:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setIcon(int id);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no a method to do so. What you will have to do is setting a custom view to your dialog. Here it's explained: [Creating a Custom Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog)

Comment: I am trying custom dialog but its taking some deafault space for the title(I dont want to draw title)...  but I want to draw Icon at the first of dialog...